# How do i set up external access for my locally hosted app? (mac)

Tags: django, macos, networking

I am having trouble setting up the a web app with external access. I am using MacOs High Sierra, I have a django app running on port 8000. Port 8000 is forwarded to the machine's internal ip in router settings.

App loads via localhost (`localhost:8000`)

Firewall is disabled

App loads correctly via internal ip (`192.168.1.4:8000`)

Connection times out via external ip (`*.*.*.*:8000`)

My intention is to access the app via external ip. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the Django development server to the `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) only. To listen on all available IP addresses, use `0.0.0.0`, i.e.:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: This helped with access via internal IP

Comment: If it works with localhost and 192.168.1.4 but not with your external IP; it means that there is something wrong with your NAT/firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If your internal network use private network and if you are behind a NAT you have to configure it. Your NAT change the private IP of your packet with is own public IP. Then he send your packet to it's destination and the destination device reply to the NAT (public IP) and then the NAT send this response to the correct device in your LAN (with private IP). That's how private home networks can reach the end of the world and that's why private home network have only one IP see by INTERNET (the IP of the NAT).

If you want to reach your internal WEB server you have to perform reverse NAT. Open the port (8000 in this case) in your NAT. Then configure it to redirect the packets to the good internal device (the private IP of your server).

Then connect to the public IP of your NAT from INTERNET with the port 8000. Done.

[image: NAT]

I suggest you to check course about NAT and Reverse NAT that will be more clear than me.

Good luck.

(Be care about the security of your server if you open the connection to internet).